# Discord.js Assign a role based off a certain message reaction

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, roles

I Want it so if a member does a certain reaction to a certain message. it will give them a role.
i know how to add a role

```
let role6 = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Member");
if(!role6) return;
user.roles.add(role6);
```

but I'm not sure who to get it to be triggered by a :white_check_mark: reaction to a certain message in a channel. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) event, which will emit when someone reacts to a message.

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
 if (reaction.message.id !== 'Message ID') return;
 const role6 = member.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name == 'Member');
 if (!role6) return;
 reaction.guild.member(user).roles.add(role6);
});
```

Comment: error message = Message Is not defined - what should I do?

Comment: Ah, sorry, that was a mistake on my end. Replace `message` with [`reaction.message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=message)

Comment: ah okay, cheers. is there a way to edit it, so it will only add a role for a certain reaction?

Comment: If it's a unicode emoji, such as ✅, you can use `if (reaction.emoji.name === ✅)`. If it's a custom emoji, you can use `if (reaction.emoji.id === 'Emoji ID')`